# trying to remove all margins so that plot region comprises the entire graphic

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to remove all margins and the "figure region" of a plot in R, so that the plot region comprises the entire graphic device.  I thought the code below would do it, but there is still a border around my plot (wider on left/bottom, thinner on top/right).  Thanks

```
par(oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
par(plt=c(0, 1, 0, 1))
```

Thought I would add a picture to show my progress.  The xaxs and yaxs removed nearly all border from the top and right- there is still a border on the left and bottom.

[image: R plot]

The relevant portion of my script is below.

```
png("Test.png", 
     width = 256, height = 256,
     units = "px", pointsize = 6.4, 
     bg = "black", res = NA)

par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), xaxs='i', yaxs='i')


smoothScatter(lhb$px, lhb$pz, nrpoints=0, xlim=c(-3,3), ylim=c(0,5), 
    main="", xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE, 
    colramp=colorRampPalette(c("black", "#202020", "#736AFF", "cyan", "yellow", "#F87431", "#FF7F00", "red", "#7E2217"))
    )

segments(.83, 1.597, .83, 3.436, col = par("fg"), lty = par("lty"), lwd = par("lwd"))
segments(-.83, 1.597, -.83, 3.436, col = par("fg"), lty = par("lty"), lwd = par("lwd"))
segments(-.83, 3.436, .83, 3.436, col = par("fg"), lty = par("lty"), lwd = par("lwd"))
segments(-.83, 1.597, .83, 1.597, col = par("fg"), lty = par("lty"), lwd = par("lwd"))


dev.off()
```

Answer (score 20):

One issue is fundamentally not getting what `plt` does. From `?par` we have:

```
 ‘plt’ A vector of the form ‘c(x1, x2, y1, y2)’ giving the
      coordinates of the plot region as fractions of the current
      figure region.
```

So your plot region is of zero size if you do `par(plt=c(1, 1, 1, 1))`, so that doesn't seem to be the way to go. This is because the figure region *contains* the plot region.

This plot seems to cover the entire region, without any margins:

```
op <- par(mar = rep(0, 4))
plot(1:10)
par(op)
```

it covers it so well you can't see the axes or the box:

[image: full region covered]

This assumes the default for 0 outer margin (`oma`). Is this what you were looking for?

We can see that just adjusting the plot margins, as above, we also change the `plt` parameter as a side effect:

```
> par("plt")
[1] 0.1173174 0.9399106 0.1457273 0.8828467
> op <- par(mar = rep(0, 4))
> par("plt")
[1] 0 1 0 1
> par(op)
> par("plt")
[1] 0.1173174 0.9399106 0.1457273 0.8828467
```

indicating that simply setting the plot margins is sufficient to get a plot/figure region encompassing the entire device.

Of course, there is still a bit of internal padding that insures the ranges of the axes are slightly large than the range of the data in both the `x` and `y` coordinates. But you can control this with `xaxs` and `yaxs` --- see `?par`

**Update:** As the OP has shown the sort of figure they are trying to produce without margins, I can provide a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100*100), ncol = 100, nrow = 100)

layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
image(dat)
op <- par(mar = rep(0, 4))
image(dat)
par(op)
layout(1)
```

which gives for comparison:

[image: comparison of default and no margins respectively]

and showing just the full plotting region:

[image: full plot region covered]

Comment: thanks for correction on plt(), I discovered this at the same time you were writing your reply and changed it to plt(0,1,0,1) above. Will look into the other suggestions as well.

Comment: @taglius - but you don't need it at all if you set `par(mar = rep(0, 4))`. By setting zero margins, `plt` will be set to `c(0,1,0,1)`. See a minor update to my answer in a minute.

Comment: That looks correct, setting par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), xaxs='i', yaxs='i')
as in my script above gets completely rid of the top and right sides.  Now I just need to get rid of the left/bottom

Comment: @geotheory what are "spatial plots"? I can well imagine what you are seeing is the effect of equal scaling on the axes, which means you can get white space that isn't margin if the aspect ratio of the device doesn't match that of the spatial domain.

Comment: As in when you plot a spatialPolygonsDataFrame. Fix is add `xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i"` to `plot.window(...)`.

Comment: I noticed that with the `axes=FALSE` option, I had a thin border around my `image(...)`. By removing this parameter, I was able to obtain full field rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the clip region parameter 'xpd' to NA ( clipped to device).

par(xpd = NA)